# Using .split() inside for loops in Python gives an error

Tags: python, list, for-loop, split

Using the following code:

```
def printformatted(statuses):
    for status in statuses:
        statusid, statussummary = status.split(",",1)
        print "\nSnapshot id: %s" % statusid
        print   "Summary:     %s" % statussummary
    print
```

`printformatted("1,Some summary")` gives me the error `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`, whereas `printformatted(["1,Some summary"])` does not.
Why?

Comment: Did you mean to take `*statuses` not `statuses`?

Comment: @Lattyware Pardon? Could you give me an example, or explain what the * operator would do? If I'm not wrong, using it in a function allows that function to work with an undefined number of arguments, like C's `printf()`. If so, would a for loop be able to iterate on it?

Comment: `*statuses` would mean that `statuses` would be a list other arguments, so it would mean you could call `printformatted('grijesh,chauah', 'yourname,secondname')` instead of `printformatted(['grijesh,chauah', 'yourname,secondname'])`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you're passing a string, so `for status in statuses` iterates over the string, character by character, which is not what you want.

In the second case, you're passing a list, so `for status in statuses` iterates over its elements, first element being `"1,Some summary"`.

Comment: I think I'd eventually have figured it out, but thanks to you, I solved my doubt in less than a minute - albeit dying in shame for having bothered the community for such a trivial matter. Thanks!